# Spring boot oauth2 response with redirect url as underlying service instead of proxy (Gateway)

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I am implementing oauth2 server using Springboot

I have four microservices

1. Sales (sales)
2. Inventory (inventory)
3. IAM service (Authorization Server, with Oauth2) (http://iam:8089)
4. Gateway (gateway on http://www.gateway.com)

All these services are behind the Spring clould gateway, and its deployed under K8S, And  **Gateway** is exposed as external interface.

Now if I try to do authenticat user using oauth2 throught gateway like below.

Step 1 :

**Http Request** http://www.gateway.com/oauth/authorize

So in Response header I am getting like

**Location**: http://iam:8089/v1/oauth/login (But expectation is http://www.gateway.com/oauth/login)

and because of that browser
redirect me to http://iam:8089/oauth/login

Where Ideally I am expecting that also routed through gateway service something like

http://www.gateway.com/oauth/login

Can someone please help me to solve this.

Thanks
Alpesh

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good setup in line with what we recommend at Curity in our [IAM Primer Article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/), with the Authorization Server (AS) behind a reverse proxy or gateway.

In your case the AS listens at http://Iam:8089 but that is an internal URL. The AS also has a 'Base URL' that is used by internet clients, and this is the URL of the gateway, which is http://www.gateway.com in your example:

- It will be returned to clients in OpenID Connect discovery requests
- It will be returned to browsers in browser redirects during authentication

There should be somewhere in Spring OAuth2 Server where you set the Base URL, similar to that in the Curity Identity Server (see image below). The process should be to set this value and then verify that it is returned in a metadata request. You should then be configured correctly.

[image]

In Spring I expect the setting you need is in the fluent configuration somewhere - maybe one of the [Configurer classes](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html#resource-server-configuration). I find it pretty hard to find what I'm looking for in Spring though.